# Firebase Facebook Authentication gives error Refused to display <oauth redirect url> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My login with firebase was working fine yet, since today and apparently without any change, I'm getting this error:

```
 Refused to display <oauth redirect url> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'
```

And the login does not get through. I'm using firebase 5.5.3 but with 6.3.0 (latest) is exactly the same.

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

        provider.addScope('public_profile,email');
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
console.log(result);
});
```

It won't even log the result...

Any advise regarding this?

Answer (score 10):

This is an issue with Firebase Hosting.  It's being addressed.

In the future, if something changes drastically, please [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) so they can collect information and escalate to engineering as needed.